# What does the Jekyll `safe` flag mean?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

The [Jekyll documentation for creating custom plugins](http://cobyism.com/jekyll/docs/plugins/) talks about a `safe` flag. The description it gives is:

> **safe** - A boolean flag that informs Jekyll whether this plugin may be safely executed in an environment where arbitrary code execution is not allowed.

I'm having a difficult time understanding that explanation. What exactly is meant by "arbitrary code"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a core plugin (one bundled with Jekyll), `safe: true` basically means the plugin will be allowed on Github Pages.

For example, say there was a plugin which parsed something like this in the user-supplied `.markdown`:

```
{% execute_shell "ls | wc -l" %}
```

..and executed the command, and included the output in the generated post. Github would not want such a plugin to be enabled, as it would allow anyone to execute arbitrary shell commands on their servers (something which makes security much harder), thus it would be marked as `safe: false`

In contrast, a plugin which, for example, automatically converts `mr@example.com` into a clickable link doesn't have any inherent security problems, so could be marked as `safe:true` and run on Github's servers without worry

Answer (score 1):

I think what it means is that it is a flag that is boolean (can either be true or false) that lets Jekyll know that the plugin you are attaching the safe flag to can be safely used when a person cannot inject code into it (essentially putting in their own programming code when inputting data).

In essence, the safe flag means that the plugin is safe to use in a normal environment for a, say, user of that environment.